# C# WebClient.DownloadFile to specific path

Tags: c#, location, output

Hi i'm trying to download a png file and place it in a custom location and i have tried adding to the line but wc.DownloadFile does not allow 3 arguments. does anyone have a suggestion? (rookie programmer)

if i change wc.DownloadFile to wc.DownloadFileAsync it gives me an error on y[2]

```
                string lookat = args[0];
                string[] exploded = lookat.Split('/');
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Proxy = new WebProxy();
                string content = wc.DownloadString(args[0]);
                Regex rx = new Regex("data-id=\"(.*)\">");
                MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(content);
                string uri = "http://" + exploded[2] + "/v2/photo/=";

                string id = matches[0].ToString().Replace("\"", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("data-id=", "");
                content = wc.DownloadString(uri + id);
                string[] res = content.Split(new string[] { "filetobedownloaded_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                foreach (string s in res)
                {
                    if (s.Contains(".png"))
                    {
                        string[] y = s.Replace("\\", "").Split('"');
                        wc.DownloadFile(y[2], "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", ".jpg"));
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DownloadFileAsync` accepts `Uri` and not `string` so you should convert your download link to `Uri` like this:

```
wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(y[2]), "C:\\" + "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", ".jpg"));
```

Comment: i have just added all the code instead of only the download code.

Comment: didn't it solve your problem? what is the error you are getting now?

Comment: no unfortunatly not..
y[2] = "cannot convert from string to System.Uri" and if i do - wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(y[2]), "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", ".jpg"), @"C:\OUTPUTFOLDER\")); it says "cannot convert from string to bool"

Comment: just coppied your code and replacing the problem line with `wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(y[2]), "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", ".jpg"));` worked for me

Comment: Now its ok with no errors, but where do i define the specified path to save the file after download? i have tried this now, it does not show an error put does not put out the file anywhere - 

                            string output = @"C:\OUTPUT\";
                            string[] y = s.Replace("\\", "").Split('"');
                            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(y[2]), "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", ".jpg ") + output);

Comment: the second argument is the full file path for example : `wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(y[2]), "C:\\a.jpg");` make sure that you are giving it a correct path

Comment: ok i tried : wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(y[2]), "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", "C:\\OUTPUT\\.jpg")); and no file showed

Comment: you are passing 3 arguments. while you should have 2: `wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(y[2]), "C:\\" + "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", "C:\\OUTPUT\\.jpg");`

Comment: Either way its not working, and if i remove the output location so it only save the file at the start location of the .exe it only downloads one of the photos and not all photos available at url if i convert it back to the original code : wc.DownloadFile(y[2], "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", ".jpg")); then it finds and downloads all three photos on my internal test link

Comment: well you should provide different download file name for each of them otherwise it will download and replace the old ones.

Comment: that is been taking care of by the above code. if i do the original code it saves three photos named "filetobedownloaded_id.jpg" and for every photo the id changes. and ofcourse i will change the "filetobedownloaded" before completing the code thats just for reference right now

Comment: i figured it out! this did it : wc.DownloadFile(y[2], output + "filetobedownloaded_" + y[0].Replace("_png", ".jpg")); and made a string name : string output = @"C:\OUTPUT\";

Comment: You are welcome. its actually what I was trying to say, if you read my previous comments

Comment: yea i kinda figured that out.. but im still new at coding so i guess i misunderstood some things :-)